# Can float3 enjoy CUDA memory coalescing?

Tags: cuda

From my understanding, only accessing memory by 4 bytes, 8 bytes or 16 bytes per thread can enjoy CUDA global memory coalescing. Following this, the frequently used float3 is a <strike>6</strike>12-byte type and is ruled out for coalescing. Am I right?

Comment: `float3` is a 12 byte type.

Comment: you are right Robert, that's a little embarrassing hahaha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tl;dr: The concept of a `float3` doesn't exist at the level where coalescing happens. So the question whether or not a `float3` will be coalesced is actually not the right question to ask. At least it's not a question that can, in general, be answered. A question that *can* be answered would be: "Will the loads/stores generated by this particular kernel here that is using `float3` in this particular way end up being coalesced?" Unfortunately, even that question can only really be answered by looking at machine code and, most importantly, profiling…

---

All current CUDA architectures support 1-Byte, 2-Byte, 4-Byte, 8-Byte, and 16-Byte global memory loads and stores. It is important to understand here that this does not mean that, e.g., a hypothetical 12-Byte load/store will happen via some other mechanism. It means that global memory can be accessed through 1-Byte, 2-Byte, 4-Byte, 8-Byte, or 16-Byte loads and stores. And that's it; period. There are *no* ways to access global memory other than through these 1-Byte, 2-Byte, 4-Byte, 8-Byte, or 16-Byte loads and stores. In particular, there are no 12-Byte loads and stores.

`float3` is an abstraction that exists at the CUDA C++ language level. The hardware doesn't have the slightest idea what a `float3` is supposed to be. All the hardware understands when it comes to global memory is that you can load or store either 1, 2, 4, 8, or 16 Bytes at once. A CUDA C++ `float3` [consists of](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#built-in-vector-types) three floats. A `float` (in CUDA) is 4 Byte wide. Accessing an element of a `float3` will, thus, generally just map to a 4-Byte load/store. Accessing all elements of a `float3` will typically result in three 4-Byte loads/stores. For example:

```
__global__ void test(float3* dest)
{
    dest[threadIdx.x] = { 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f };
}
```

If you [look at the PTX assembly](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:cuda,source:'%0A%0A__global__+void+test(float3*+dest)%0A%7B%0A++++dest%5BthreadIdx.x%5D+%3D+%7B+1.0f,+2.0f,+3.0f+%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'CUDA+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+NVCC+9.2',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:59.112271540469976,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:nvcc92,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:cuda,libs:!(),options:'',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'NVCC+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+CUDA',t:'0')),k:40.887728459530024,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) the compiler generates for this kernel, you will see that assigning `{ 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f }` to our `float3` compiled down to three 4-Byte stores:

```
    mov.u32         %r2, 1077936128;
    st.global.u32   [%rd4+8], %r2;
    mov.u32         %r3, 1073741824;
    st.global.u32   [%rd4+4], %r3;
    mov.u32         %r4, 1065353216;
    st.global.u32   [%rd4], %r4;
```

These are just normal loads/stores like any other, there is nothing special about them. And these individual loads/stores are subject to potential coalescing like any other load/store. In this particular example, the memory access pattern will look like this:

```
1st store:  xx xx t1 xx xx t2 xx xx t3 xx xx t4 xx xx t5 xx xx t6 …
2nd store:  xx t1 xx xx t2 xx xx t3 xx xx t4 xx xx t5 xx xx t6 xx …
3rd store:  t1 xx xx t2 xx xx t3 xx xx t4 xx xx t5 xx xx t6 xx xx …
```

Where t*i* is the *i*-th thread of your warp and `xx` denotes a skipped 4-Byte address. As you can see, there are 8-Byte gaps between the stores performed by our threads. However there are still quite a few 4-Byte stores that all fall within the same 128-Byte cache line. Thus, the access pattern does still allow for *some* coalescing (on any current architecture), it's just far from ideal. But some is better than nothing. See [the CUDA documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#global-memory-3-0) for more detail on that.

Please note that all of this really solely depends on what memory access patterns the generated machine code gives rise to in the end. Whether or not, and, if so, to which degree memory access can be coalesced has nothing to do with the use of a particular data type at the C++ level. To illustrate this point, consider the following example:

```
struct Stuff
{
    float3 p;
    int blub;
};

__global__ void test(Stuff* dest)
{
    dest[threadIdx.x].p = { 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f };
    dest[threadIdx.x].blub = 42;
}
```

[Looking at the PTX assembly](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:cuda,source:'%0Astruct+Stuff%0A%7B%0A++++float3+p%3B%0A++++int+blub%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A__global__+void+test(Stuff*+dest)%0A%7B%0A++++dest%5BthreadIdx.x%5D.p+%3D+%7B+1.0f,+2.0f,+3.0f+%7D%3B%0A++++dest%5BthreadIdx.x%5D.blub+%3D+42%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'CUDA+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+NVCC+9.2',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:59.112271540469976,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:nvcc92,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:cuda,libs:!(),options:'',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'NVCC+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+CUDA',t:'0')),k:40.887728459530024,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4), we see that the compiler translated this C++ code into four individual 4-Byte stores. No surprises so far. Let's slightly modify this code

```
struct alignas(16) Stuff
{
    float3 p;
    int blub;
};

__global__ void test(Stuff* dest)
{
    dest[threadIdx.x].p = { 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f };
    dest[threadIdx.x].blub = 42;
}
```

and notice that, suddenly, the compiler [has turned all of this into a single 16-Byte store](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:cuda,source:'%0Astruct+alignas(16)+Stuff%0A%7B%0A++++float3+p%3B%0A++++int+blub%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A__global__+void+test(Stuff*+dest)%0A%7B%0A++++dest%5BthreadIdx.x%5D.p+%3D+%7B+1.0f,+2.0f,+3.0f+%7D%3B%0A++++dest%5BthreadIdx.x%5D.blub+%3D+42%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'CUDA+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+NVCC+9.2',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:59.112271540469976,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:nvcc92,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:cuda,libs:!(),options:'',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'NVCC+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+CUDA',t:'0')),k:40.887728459530024,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4). Knowing that a `Stuff` object is guaranteed to always sit at a 16 Byte boundary and that, by the rules of the C++ language, the individual modifications of the struct members here are not observable in any particular order by another thread, the compiler can fuse all these assignments into one 16-Byte store, which ultimately leads to an access pattern like

```
t1 t1 t1 t1 t2 t2 t2 t2 t3 t3 t3 t3 t4 t4 t4 t4 …
```

Another example:

```
__global__ void test(float3* dest)
{
    auto i = threadIdx.x % 3;
    auto m = i == 0 ? &float3::x : i == 1 ? &float3::y : &float3::z;
    dest[threadIdx.x / 3].*m = i;
}
```

Here, we're writing to a `float3` array again. However, every thread [will perform](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:cuda,source:'%0A%0A__global__+void+test(float3*+dest)%0A%7B%0A++++auto+i+%3D+threadIdx.x+%25+3%3B%0A++++auto+m+%3D+i+%3D%3D+0+%3F+%26float3::x+:+i+%3D%3D+1+%3F+%26float3::y+:+%26float3::z%3B%0A++++dest%5BthreadIdx.x+/+3%5D.*m+%3D+i%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'CUDA+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+NVCC+9.2',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:59.112271540469976,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:nvcc92,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:cuda,libs:!(),options:'',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'NVCC+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+CUDA',t:'0')),k:40.887728459530024,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) exactly one store to one of the members of a `float3`, and consecutive threads will store to consecutive 4-Byte addresses, leading to perfectly-coalesced memory access:

```
t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7 t8 t9 t10 t11 t12 t13 t14 t15 …
```

Again, the fact that our C++ code, at some point, was using a `float3` is itself completely irrelevant. What is relevant is what it is that we're actually doing, what loads/stores are generated, and what the access pattern looks like as a result…